# Walking a twisted path on a donut - a Möbius Slitherlink

Tags: logical-deduction, grid-deduction, slitherlink

<sub>This puzzle is part of the [Monthly Topic Challenge #13: Variety Slitherlinks](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7488/monthly-topic-challenge-13-variety-slitherlinks).</sub>

---

Have you ever wondered why there has to be an "inside" and an "outside" to every slitherlink loop?

Well, with a bit of rule-bending (grid-bending really) everything can be on the inside (or the outside if you prefer). All you have to do is wrap your grid around a torus so that it has no edges.

And just to add a bit more variety: Now that we have every cell on the same side of the loop, let's also require that <strike>there be a unique shortest path (travelling orthogonally) between every pair of cells.</strike> the path through the cells is narrow and twisty - no big open spaces.<sup>*</sup>

- Draw a single, non-intersecting loop that only consists of horizontal and vertical segments between the dots.
- The edges of the grid are joined (left-to-right and top-to-bottom) so that the grid is topologically a torus. The loop can travel off the left/right side of the grid and back on the right/left side (and similarly top/bottom).
- Numbers inside a cell indicate how many of the edges of that cell are part of the loop.
- <strike>There must be a unique shortest path between every pair of cells (travelling orthogonally and not crossing the loop).</strike>
- The path must be "narrow" - there must be no contiguous 2x2 block of cells inside the loop.<sup>*</sup>

[image: Grid for Mobius slitherlink on a torus]

[Solve on Penpa here](https://tinyurl.com/moebius-donut)
To get the solution checker to work, the left/right and top/bottom joined edges must be consistent (draw the loop on both where it travels along the edge of the grid).

<sup>* My attempt to hide the "no 2x2" restriction behind a unique path constraint failed because there is a cycle in the path that goes all the way around the torus. Trying to fix this with "shortest" also fails for even-width grids like this one because the total cycle length is even and for suitable pairs of points, the shortest distance is the same either way round.</sup>

Comment: Oh, sorry! I'll repost in rot13: rot13(Fbzrguvat V'ir abgvprq: Sbe rirel 2k2 frpgvba bs gur tevq, gur fyvgureyvax unf gb cnff guebhtu gung, bgurejvfr gurer jba'g or n havdhr cngu.)

Comment: I'm confused about the torus requirement. Do the top and bottom edges have to have the same configuration?

Comment: @newQOpenWid The top and bottom edges are common, because they would be joined together if you actually deformed the grid into a torus.

Comment: When you say there should be a unique "shortest path" between any two cells, I think you mean there must be a unique path.

Comment: And, sorry to nitpick, but a "Möbius strip" has a twist.  To make a Möbius strip you should for instance match the top from left to right with the bottom from right to left, and leave the sides disconnected.  If you mean the path has a single side, it is not the case.  If the path were a wall and you painted one side of it from end to end, so to speak, you would still leave one side unpainted.  This being said, it is still a great puzzle.

Comment: @FlorianF Regarding unique paths, I thought so too until I discovered a ring going all the way round the torus that gives you multiple (two) paths between some pairs of cells . So I had to come up with some clunky wording that achieved the same constraint.  Not sure yet if that's always going to happen on a torus, or is just a feature of this particular puzzle.

Comment: @FlorianF nitpicking is fine. I was just using a bit of poetic license for having a closed loop that doesn't have an inside and outside any more. But you are correct that the loop itself still has two "sides".

Comment: I see your point about "shortest".  You almost made me agree with you.  But thinking about it, if the large loop has even length you can go halfway around in two ways of equal length.  So in fact you would need the width to be odd to be perfectly tight.

Comment: Executive pleading for everyone to pause on this problem for a while, because I am *really* close to an answer.

Comment: @FlorianF hmm. I may have to give up on path uniqueness, and just openly state the required restriction. (Which is pretty obvious anyway.)

Comment: So... How do you solution check?

Comment: As long as you use green edges it will automatically tell you when you have them all correct. (Assuming I set it up correctly, don't worry if it doesn't work)

Comment: My solution appears to still separate the torus into two sections. Is this fine?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147917/discussion-between-new-q-open-wid-and-fljx).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What a great puzzle! The following is a solution:

> [image: solution]

The key:

> is to look at the 1s. In most cases they are not very important, but here 1s, alongside the shortest path rule (which turns into a restriction that every 2x2 square has to have a path through it) provide a large amount of information. Specifically, if two 1s are diagonal, the line cannot be 'around' them, or else it would lead to a contradiction.

We start by using the above rule and the

> zero in the bottom-right corner. We can then easily deduce that there have to be lines pointing in to the zero. Similarly the setup of 1s in the left side of the grid allows for us to deduce a large amount of information.

I have liberally used this rule:

> To keep the shortest-paths/2x2 grid law intact, if in a 2x2 square two X's are drawn in the following formation, then we must have two lines pointing out. [image: rule]

I started with

> [image: start point] and made deductions to get to the final solution.

Comment: Well done. This is the intended solution.